# should I do many smaller requests, or fewer but larger requests using s3 to pass data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm working on a project that requires data entries to be inserted into an RDS instance. We're using a serverless stack (cognito, api gateway, lambda, rds) to accomplish this. Our application requires a large amount of data to be read off of an embedded device, prior to insertion. That data must then be inserted immediately.

Based on our current setup, a single batch of data could be in excess of 60KB, but that's a worst case scenario.

Is there an accepted best practice or ideal way of sending/accessing this data this large in my lambda function? As of right now, I'm planning on shipping it off with my API request. I've seen s3 mentioned as an intermediary for large quantities of data, but I'm not sure if it's really necessary for something like this.

Comment: One thing to consider would be if you'll trigger a rate limit on connections. Lots of rapid small connections could cause you hit a cap and have subsequent requests dropped until the period expires or be treated as a DoS attack and temporarily blacklisted. Check with the S3 documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience it depends on a number of factors. What communication are you using? What is the drop rate? do you experience corrupt packages? What is your embedded device?

If you can send the data in one time with a 97% success rate then I don't see a reason to split the data. If packets take a long time and connections can drop then its good to send multiple packets and resend the failed ones.

For the network 60KB is a small amount of data. If you have a slow 2G embedded device then that's your bottleneck and you need to experience what the most efficient way is to get the data out of it. A single stream of data would probably be the most efficient.